# .NET 6 TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId() does return false

Tags: .net, windows, timezone, .net-6.0

On Windows Server 2019 Version 10.0.17763 the following code returns false:

```
TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId("W. Europe Standard Time", out var timeZoneIana)
```

But this code worked on a test machine with Windows Server 2022.
What are the system requirements for this method to work?

Comment: What's the actual Windows version of the test machine? Besides, that call isn't very useful unless you specify a region, eg `TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId("W. Europe Standard Time", "AT",out var timeZoneIana);`. Otherwise you get a default, `Europe/Berlin` that's simply wrong unless you live in Germany

Comment: Ah I just realized that the test machine is Windows Server 2022. Is that call not supported under Windows Server 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods `TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId` and `TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertIanaIdToWindowsId` rely on [ICU globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu), which is available on Windows machines as of the Windows 10 May 2019 update.  That corresponds to Windows Server 1903 (build 10.0.18362).

If you need to support Windows and IANA time zones on older systems, use the [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) library instead.  The corresponding method is `TZConvert.TryWindowsToIana`.

Comment: You didn't mention TimeZoneConverter is your library. :) Hope you don't mind if I ask a quick question here rather than open a new issue on your GIthub - does it now work with .NET WASM (6.0 or higher)? The WASM runtime now has time zone infos built in but it uses Iana instead of Windows IDs, and TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId always fails in WASM.

Comment: Also want to point out for everyone's benefit that since Windows Server 2019's last long term release was 1809 and you can't in-place upgrade to 1903, in most cases you'd need to be using Windows Server 2022 to get this feature. Frustrating...

Comment: It should, as there are no runtime dependencies.  Give it a try. :)

Comment: Oh sure I will try it. The only thing I was unsure about was unzipping the embedded data resources. Never tried that in WASM but will give it a go, thanks.